# How can I write a code for the following C functions using structure, malloc and array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

create a structure called arrayData that contains an integer pointer called array and an integer variable called size.

create a function with the following header: arrayData* createArray(int size). Inside this function you will malloc space for a new arrayData structure. You will then need to create an array using the input variable as the number of elements. Finally you will need to set the variables in the malloc'ed arrayData pointer equal to the array and the array size. Finally return the pointer of malloc'ed arrayData structure.

here is the code for above terms:

```
struct arrayData
{
    int *array;
    int size;

};


struct arrayData* createArray(int size)
{
    struct arrayData *str = (struct arrayData*)malloc(sizeof(struct arrayData));
    int a = 10;
    str->array = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    str->size = size;
    for ( a = 0; a < 10; a++ )
    {
        str->array[i] = a; 
    }
    return str;
}
```

I addition I want to do something like:
Create a function with the following header: void printArray(arrayData *data). This function will print out all values in the array of the input variable.
The outpu will look like the following:
value1
value2
value3
value4

Create a function with the following header: void freeMem(arrayData *data). In this function you will free all memory that has been malloc'ed.

can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: I think you will find that you will get more help if you show what you have so far. You know what the function prototypes should look like, start there. This sounds like a homework problem, so I'm guessing you will have some references to consult.

Answer (score 0):

For printing the array.

```
  void printArray(struct arrayData *data) {
      int i;
      for(i=0;<data->size;i++) {
          printf("\t%d",data->array[i]);
      }
  }
```

To free

```
   void freeMem(struct arrayData *data) {
         free(data->array);
         free(data);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the size of array (size) is not correlated with the storing of the 'a' value into the array.  (It isn't clear that a < size.)

```
printArray(arrayData *data) {  
    for (i = 0; i < data->size; i++) {  
        printf("%d ", data->array[i]);  
    }  
    printf("\n");  
}  

freeMem(arrayData *data) {  
    free(data->array);  
    free(data);  
}
```

I haven't declared i, etc.  No prototypes, etc.  Just fill them in.